# Duplicated featured image is not showing

Tags: post-thumbnails

I have a site where I upload Apkmod file that's why I have to upload dozens of post daily but some time by mistake I upload the same post with the same feature image and I don't want my site work slowly and also I don't want old same images. So I just delete the old post with the same name and keep the new post on my site when I delete the old post I  also delete the Featured image who is attached with the post but the problem is when I delete the old post and there feature image then my new post Featured image is not showing I don't know what is the problem please help me[image]

Comment: You have stated the problem in your question.  You deleted the image.  WordPress cannot show an image that has been deleted from the CMS